# Blogger API: post an article with label in PHP

Tags: php, blogger

By using Blogger API, I want to post an article with several labels in PHP. At the moment, the articles are posted with success, but labels are not added. Here my code:

```
  $blogId = "myBlogId";
  $data = array("kind" => "blogger#post", "blog" => array("id" => $blogId), "title" => "test", "content" => "content", "labels" => ["t1", "t2"]);  
  $data = json_encode($data);

  $curlObj = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/'.$blogId.'/posts?key='.$myApiKey);
  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json', 'Authorization: OAuth '.$accessToken));
  curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  $response = curl_exec($curlObj);

  curl_close($curlObj);
```

The response does not return error and the post is visible in my Blogger but without labels. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to insert post using the following code.
First of all get the **access token**, set the access token and then pass authenticated `$client` to `the Google_Service_Blogger()` class.

```
public function insert_post( $blogId, $postBody ) {
    $Blogger = new Google_Service_Blogger( $this->client );
    $NewPost = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();

    // set title
    if ( isset( $postBody['title'] ) ) {
        $NewPost->setTitle( $postBody['title'] );
    }

    // set content
    if ( isset( $postBody['content'] ) ) {
        $NewPost->setContent($postBody['content'] );
    }

    // set labels
    if ( isset( $postBody['labels'] ) ) {
        $NewPost->setLabels( $postBody['labels'] );
    }


    $response = [];
    try {
        $response['post'] = $Blogger->posts->insert( $blogId, $NewPost );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $response['error'] = $e;
    }

    return $response;
}
```